# Inequality convolution distribution function

Tags: probability-inequalities

$F$ is the distribution function of a positive random variable.
Why does the following hold for every $x \in (0,\infty)$:

$F^{*2}(x) \leq F^2(x)$, where

$F^{*2}=F*F=\int\limits_0^x F(x-y)dF(y)$

Comment: Is there a particular point you are stuck on? What have you tried?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please use the homework tag so that we can answer it accordingly!

Comment: **Hint**: Use monotonicity twice. First, for an arbitrary distribution function $F$ and, second, for the integral.

Comment: This is not homework. I've tried rewriting it as: $0 \leq \left(\int\limits_0^x dF(y)\right)^2 - \int\limits_0^x F(x-y)dF(y)  $. But how do I show this?

Comment: Note also that the nonnegativity restriction allows for an alternate simple probabilistic proof requiring no calculation at all. What might that be?

Comment: @cardinal +1 for a great comment!  Once again, you have suggested the answer to Chris's question with a one-liner. (I like this one better than your earlier suggestion).

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Thanks. I couldn't decide whether to post a version of the latter as an answer or not. :)

Comment: It is also possible to derive the result from integration by parts.

Comment: Maybe a one liner isn't clear enough.  I think what cardinal was saying is that F(x-y)<=F(x) for every y>o.  Use that inequality to substitute into the integral.

Comment: @Michael, yes, that is the idea for the first hint. I think Dilip was referring to my second one though, where no calculation or reference to $F$ at all is required.

Comment: Okay: But I think the important thing is not how elegant the hint is but rather whether or not the OP understood it.

Comment: I see, so there is a short approach, where the integral does not have to be evaluated at all. Should I revisit the definition of the convolution for this?

Comment: Chris, yes to your first statement and no to the second. What you should think about is the probabilistic reason for *how* the convolution would arise in the first place.

Comment: Since this discussion does not seem to be converging, let me add to @cardinal's hint.  One of the two expressions is $P\{X+Y \leq x\}$ and the other is $P\{X \leq x, Y \leq x\}$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent identically distributed positive random variables with common distribution function $F(\cdot)$.  One of the two sets $\{X+Y \leq x\}, \{X \leq x, Y \leq x\}$ is a subset of the other. So no integral need be evaluated.

Comment: I see: $F^{*2}(x,y)=P(X+Y \leq x) \leq P(X \leq x, Y \leq x)=F(x,y)$. But why is $P(X+Y \leq x) \leq (P(X \leq x, Y \leq x))^2$ ?

Comment: >"But why is $P(X+Y\leq x)\leq (P(X\leq x,Y\leq x))^2$?" Nobody claimed that it was. You need to use independence of $X$ and $Y$ and avoid undefined undefined symbols such as $y$ and undefined notation such as $F(x,y)$ in your first sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer by Dilip Sarwate and cardinal:

$F^{*2}(x)=P(X+Y \leq x) \leq P(X \leq x, Y \leq x)=F^{2}(x).$

Thank you very much!

Comment: (+1) The key here is to recognize that $\{X+Y \leq x\} \subset \{X \leq x, Y \leq x\}$. A good follow-up is to come up with a (very!) simple counterexample to show that the result fails when $X$ can take on negative values.